# MakeFile:Force all files under directory to include header

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

My current directory looks as follow:

```
root
  |___src
  |     |
  |     |____Makefile
  |     |____a.cpp
  |     |____b.cpp
  |     |____c.h
  |     |____tests
  |              |
  |______________|____test.cpp
```

Is there a way from the makefile to force all files under tests directory to include c.h

Comment: the only way is to manually write `#include "../c.h"` in every file under tests directory

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: ...And do you want to modify the source files, or just compile them *as if* they had that `include` directive?

Comment: @Beta My plan is as follows, a.cpp and b.cpp have the exact same interface. But acpp is the production implementation and b.cpp is a fake implementation for testing. I want to make sure that b.cpp will never be deployed to prod. So in my prod makefile i will add a flag say 'DPROD'. Now in c.h I will check if the compiled version contain prod flag and if so terminate the program. I want to enforce that in each file under tests this check will be performed so that if someone comes later on and add a file and forget this include it will be automatically added from the makefile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't answered either of my questions, so I'll have to make some guesses.

This may be what you're looking for:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    @$(CXX) -c $< -o $@

tests/%.o: tests/%.cpp
    @$(CXX) -include c.h -c $< -o $@
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to insert `#include "c.h"` at the top of a source file, you can use this sed command:

```
sed -i "" '1{h;s/.*/#include "c.h"/;G;}' filename
```

If you want to be sure you don't do so more than once, you can do this:

```
sed -i "" '1{h;s/.*/#include "c.h"/;G;s/\(.*\)\n\1$/\1/;}' filename
```

There are several different ways to do this with a makefile. Here is one crude-but-effective approach:

```
tests/%.o: tests/%.cpp
    @sed -i "" '1{h;s/.*/#include "c.h"/;G;s/\(.*\)\n\1$/\1/;}' $<
    @$(CXX) -c $< -o $@
```

But Make will work better if you run sed on each source file only once. This can be done, but it requires more careful thought about priorities.

Comment: sorry I thought you wanted me to explain why i'm doing this.
Which compiler are you using?  I'm using g++
And do you want to modify the source files, or just compile them as if they had that include directive? Ideally i want to modify the source files.

Answer (score 0):

`gcc` and [`clang`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html#cmdoption-include) support `-include file` command line option.

[gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html):

> -include file
>
> Process file as if #include "file" appeared as the first line of the primary source file. However, the first directory searched for file is the preprocessor's working directory instead of the directory containing the main source file. If not found there, it is searched for in the remainder of the #include "..." search chain as normal.

Other compilers may have a similar option.

Comment: Won't this add this include to all my files i.e. a.cpp,b.cpp and test.cpp ?

Comment: @Amr it includes the header into the translation unit being compiled.